# Wordpress: let shop manager create users with custom role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to let the shop managers of my ecommerce to create users with a custom role created by me.

With this code I'm able to add the possibility for shop_manager to add users but the problem is that the shop manager can create only a user with "customer", instead I would like to let the shop manager add the custom role that I've previously created.

```
function shop_manager_add_users() {
    $role = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role->add_cap('create_users' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'shop_manager_add_users');
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just to note that the User has the Role assigned in Settings > General > New User Default Role. If this includes your default role then your code works for this (but not for both Custom Role and Customer). There will obviously be some security considerations otherwise a Shop Manager could create an Administrator

Comment: It looks like the capability you need is `promote_users` but, again you'll have security considerations. This answer may help; https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/editor-can-create-any-new-user-except-administrator

Answer (score -2):

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse42003_activation' );
function wpse42003_activation()
{
    foreach( array( 'editor', 'shop_manager' ) as $r )
    {
        $role = get_role( $r );
        if( $role )
            $role->add_cap( 'create_users' );
    }
}
```

You can try this one that was working on my site well but a few years ago

Comment: thanks but this code do the same thing that I do.
Add the capability to create users but gives me the exactly same problem that I've already have: I can create only customers

Comment: Read the question!